# Read file gives undefined when we call a function because value isnt returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, fs

I have attached snippets of the code, and outputs:
The main objective is to process an image in a particular path and produce a tensor value from the model to display it.
first the **checkViolence**() is called and the path is passed in:

```
checkViolence = async (path) => {
  const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
  const tfn = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
  const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem("./model1/model.json");
  try {
    let value = {};
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
    sharp(path)
      .resize({ height: 224, width: 224 })
      .jpeg()
      .toFile(path + " forChecking.jpg", async (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
        let s = await processData(path + " forChecking.jpg", model, tfn);
        console.log("processedData:", s);
      });
    // console.log(value);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

inside which we call **processData**() which is used to process the image as shown below:

```
processData = async (path, model, tfn) => {
  let val = fs.promises
    .readFile(path, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data:", data);
      let tensor = tfn.node.decodeJpeg(data).expandDims(0);
      let output = model.predict(tensor);
      const values = output.dataSync();
      const array1 = Array.from(values);
      console.log("in function", array1[0]);
      return array1[0]; // This value needs to be returned, can be seen in the output of previous line.
    })
  return val;
};
```

Output:

```
[0] in function 0.06445053219795227
[0] {
[0] format: 'jpeg',
[0] width: 224,
[0] height: 224,
[0] channels: 3,
[0] premultiplied: false,
[0] size: 6256
[0] }
[0] processedData: undefined
[0] data: <Buffer ff d8 ff db 00 43 00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06 06 05 06 07 07 06 08 0a 10 0a 0a 09 09 0a 14 0e 0f 0c 10 17 14 18 18 17 14 16 16 1a 1d 25 1f 1a 1b 23 1c 16 ... 6206 more bytes>
[0] in function 0.06445053219795227
```

Ps. Have tried fs.readFile and fs.readFileSync both render the same results..

Please help mee, new to async/await :(

Comment: `fs.promises.readFile` does not take a callback

Comment: Also, use `const data = await fs.promises.readFile(path);` instead of `.then()` in an `async` function

Comment: What's more worrisome: why do you get the "*in function 0.06445053219795227*" output **twice**?

Comment: seems I've been trying to use the top level function twice (cause for the two time output),  Figured out a way with the fs.promise await thanks a lot for your help solved my error :)